# Correctly translate backslashed numbers to symbols?

Tags: lua, codepages, luadec

I just decompiled a file with luadec, it does it well, and, the output not being perfect, it's still usable, but I'm getting a weird string of numbers `\198\247\184\181\188\177\177\219\183\161\189\186` that I know for a fact are in Korean language, but I do not know what they're called and basically can't find anything about them.

I just need to correctly translate the string from numbers to symbols or gibberish text, like this `c±Ý»ö´À³¦Ç¥`.

If someone could point me in the right direction I would be grateful, thanks.

Comment: My Lua interpreter gives `╞≈╕╡╝▒▒█╖í╜║`. [Doesn't look like UTF-8 though](http://software.hixie.ch/utilities/cgi/unicode-decoder/utf8-decoder).

Comment: How can I encode that myself? Sorry I have no idea how to do it, i've been trying a few online sites but they don't seem to understand the \123 notation or I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran this script with Lua

> `print"\198\247\184\181\188\177\177\219\183\161\189\186"`

and saved the output to a text file which I then loaded into Safari.

I got gibberish the default encoding. I got 포링선글래스 with Korean (Mac OS) encoding. Same thing with Korean (Windows, DOS), but not with Korean (ISO 2022-KR).

Note that escaped numbers in Lua are in *decimal*.

Comment: Sorry... any Windows alternative?

Comment: @nyanko safari isn't MacOS only ;)

Comment: I mean, the print command? I use notepad++ for switching files encoding but I'm missing the part that actually translates the numbers to gibberish.

Comment: @nyanko, I ran the script with Lua as in `lua foo.lua > foo.txt`.

Comment: Thank you, sorry I'm a total newbie to lua.